# Problem with audio driver in Acer inspire 5733Z

Tags: audio

I installed elementary OS on an Acer inspire 5733Z and I have no sound.  Is there a specific driver that I can download to solve the "no sound" problem.  The hardware is Realtek audio chip.  Anything at this stage would be useful to try.

Answer (score 1):

Go-to your terminal and try this.

```
 sudo alsa force-reload
```

And than restart your pc again. Still you face the similar problem than try this.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

And than

```
  sudo alsa force-reload
```

Now restart and check again.  It might be work now.

Comment: No success with your solution.  In the process of following the instructions I seem to have now lost the sound setting capability to check the results.  Are there any other solutions.  My sound chip is an ALC 272x if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do this and re try that again.  `sudo apt-get install dkms`.  But the Previous answer was solved my problem. Probably check your dkms before installing it.  It may help you.